# What is the derivative of this piece-wise function at x=0?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $$f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
x^{2}\sin\left(5/x\right) & \text{if }x\neq0;\\
0 & \text{if }x=0.
\end{cases}$$ Does $f'(0)$ exist, and if so, what is its value?

Comment: Use the definition of derivative at zero.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Use the definition the derivative, namely,

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\longrightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$